# Email piping in PHP like Craigslist - How do I associate real emails?

Tags: php, email, piping, craigslist

I have seen some examples of php scripts that read email headers and parse out data to send out a new email to the real email address.

One question I have is....how do I associate alias and real email addresses? Do I store alias email into MySQL and link it to the real email addresses and check it using the script?

I'm thinking of creating an alias email generator in the admin, so I can generate alias email whenever I need it for each post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your suggested method is pretty simple and works well. We often store an additional field in next to a user account that's a randomly generated email alias for this purpose.

Of course if you want to use a different one each time you can just use a new table and generate each one. You obviously just need to make sure you put a uniqueness constraint on the field to ensure that no user has the same alias. Alternatively you can make use of the disposable part of the email address so that a user gets username+changeme@example.com so you only need the one table but can still have throwaway addresses, they're a bit predictable though.